# Interactivity on map using SVG and RaphaelJS with Links

Tags: javascript, svg, maps, raphael, interactive

I've been researching the easiest way to create an interactive map for my company with a custom of USA map I've created in Illustrator. I found this tutorial: http://parall.ax/blog/view/2985/tutorial-creating-an-interactive-svg-map which is very complete and will help me ***partially*** to achieve the results im looking.

But what about when i want to add a link on click and Text on hover of the region to each area of the map?

I'm not well versed with JavaScript so I will appreciate a lot the help and understanding  from the community.

Comment: While there may be good (so far, unspecified) reasons for you choosing against it, have you considered using Google Maps? They have tons of documentation, reasonably good API wrappers, constantly up-to-date data, plenty of customization, many tutorials for them and more.

Comment: Im dividing the USA Maps in territories for a future sales team and I liked the ability of creating my own map and using it that's the reason. I read about Google Maps and some of the functions but i couldnt find what i was looking which is the ease of use of Raphael. 
I just need to know if its possible to add links to the maps like stated in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have an element called `regionShape` defined in raphael which corresponds to one of the regions in your map. Adding a link on click should be quite easy:

```
regionShape.node.onclick = function(e) {  
                               window.location.href = "somepage.html";
                           }
```

In order to display a text on hover, I would recommend using jQuery. What I normally do is define a div element `#hoverInfo` and set its css `display` property to `none`, and then modify this property with rafael `node.onmouseover`, like this:

```
regionShape.node.onmouseover = function(e) {  
            $("#hoverInfo").css("display", "block");  
        };
```

And then you remove it by using onmouseout:

```
regionShape.node.onmouseout = function(e) {  
            $("#hoverInfo").css("display", "none");  
        };
```